# Has the Apophenia C library been used for publications?

Tags: software

Are there analysis works that were conducted using the Apophenia library and were published?

This is a C library for statistical analysis. I wanted to know about use cases.

Comment: This is the right sort of question to discuss in chat.

Comment: @whuber People asked this kind of questions here. For instance, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25672/does-julia-have-any-hope-of-sticking-in-the-statistical-community

Comment: another example, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1595/python-as-a-statistics-workbench/2159#2159

Comment: You are asking a different question: yours is inquiring about the popularity of software.  The others are asking about the software itself.  I am concerned that answers will be primarily opinions without objective support.

Comment: @whuber I asked about 'fact'. I didn't even ask about whether the software is 'suitable' or not. When there are analysis works done using the library and were published, this question is answered.

Comment: Now I made the question simple and assume it wouldn't look like asking for opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Scholar returns 15 results](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C47&q=%22Apophenia%20library%22&btnG=). You can decide whether or not they're sufficiently serious.

Comment: I edited the title of the question. 14 of the search results are published by the author of the library. But the results do include one real publication case. That paper mentioned one function in the library. Thank you for the information.